Mesh can't follow curve on geometry node setup
Following this great answer here on how to map an earth map to a sphere, I downloaded the provided .blend file and encountered a problem I can't solve.
Meshes don't follow a the curved shape of the sphere as seen in this images. This is achieved through geometry nodes so I don't get much of what's happening.

What might be the problem? Blend file provided.


The author of the answer you refer to, Lutzi, explains what's the problem: bad topology = ngon. Consider something like delaunay triangulation... https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230655/60486

To say it simple: to follow a spherical surface, the mesh needs to bend/curve. A mesh can only bend where vertices and edges are. A plain face without edges inbetween cannot bend onto the sphere's surface.

Here's an idea to dynamically create supporting geometry for deformation… It's imperfect and I wouldn't be surprised if a simple mesh boolean turned out better...


rotate everything from y-up to z-up
spawn a grid with appropriate dimensions and position, I manually calculated resolution (based on reported dimensions in the Number Panel) to produce squares, and then convert them to points to dimensionless curves, which will control where to insert points in the "Fill Curve" - a trick I learned long time ago from vklidu
use a simulation for easier debugging: take one instance on each frame, flatten it, realize, merge by distance so it's one-sided, delete all splines from the bullet-point above that are outside the evaluated face, convert the face to curve, join with remaining points, fill curve (vklidu's technique), join with already processed geometry
rotate back, because I didn't want to update Lutzi's algorithm (though I did butcher out the dependency on the empty)

Result:

But wait, what's up with the Canada-USA border?

Apparently your countries have some long segments that need to be subdivided. This is what the "Resample" custom group does:

I can spot some bugs - what I would try next is to limit the effect to only big countries (use face area) or try boolean mesh instead…



thank you for you effort. can you share the blend file? it looks the one you provided is faulty

@MarioDavó I just checked and it works for me, can you describe in what way it is "faulty"?
